# Graphics Slow or Not Even Loading

Tags: java, performance, swing, graphics, timer

I made this to generate a checkerboard, and flip the tiles (switch colors) 10 times, every 10 seconds. However, the graphics either do not load, or do not update.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ShapeTest extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
private static int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
private static int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

Color color1 = Color.BLACK;
Color color2 = Color.WHITE;
javax.swing.Timer timer = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            setAttributes();
        }
    });
}

public static void setAttributes() {
    frame.add(new ShapeTest());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("FrameTest");
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/* Constructor */
public ShapeTest() {
    timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (color1 == Color.BLACK) {
                color1 = Color.WHITE;
                color2 = Color.BLACK;
                repaint();
            } else {
                color1 = Color.BLACK;
                color2 = Color.WHITE;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}

protected void painComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (int x = 0; x < FRAME_WIDTH; x = x + 10) {
        for (int y = 0; y < FRAME_HEIGHT; y = y + 10) {
            if (x % 20 == 0) {
                g.setColor(color2);
                g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
                y = y + 10;
                g.setColor(color1);
                g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
            } else {
                g.setColor(color1);
                g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
                y = y + 10;
                g.setColor(color2);
                g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
            }
        }
    }
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

}

}
```

Here is the revised code based on the answer below, however, it still doesn't seem to run.

Comment: Sorry, I spelled `paintComponent` wrong. I had it `painComponent`. Make that fix, and it works fine. I tested it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use thread sleep Thread.sleep() In a Swing program. Use a `Swing Timer.` And define a `Color` object globally, so it can be accessed from timer and `paintComponent`. Then repaint in the timer Try this out:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ShapeTest extends JPanel {
    private static int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
    private static int FRAME_WIDTH = 500;
    private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    Color color1 = Color.BLACK;                      <-- Color objects
    Color color2 = Color.WHITE;
    javax.swing.Timer timer = null;                  <-- Declare Timer object

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                setAttributes();
            }
        });
    }
    public static void setAttributes() {
         frame.add(new ShapeTest());                  <-- Add the panel
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setTitle("FrameTest");
         frame.pack();                    <--- Pack.
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /* Constructor */
    public ShapeTest(){
        timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener(){   <-- "sleeps" 5 seconds (real word is "delay")
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if (color1 == Color.BLACK){
                    color1 = Color.WHITE;                <-- Alternate colors
                    color2 = Color.BLACK; 
                    reapaint();                          <-- repaint
                } else {
                    color1 = Color.BLACK;                <-- Alternate colors
                    color2 = Color.WHITE;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();                         <-- Start timer
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

         for (int x = 0; x < FRAME_WIDTH; x = x + 10) {
             for (int y = 0; y < FRAME_HEIGHT; y = y + 10) {
                 if (x % 20 == 0) {
                     g.setColor(color2);      <-- Just us the color Object
                     g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
                     y = y + 10;
                     g.setColor(color1);
                     g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
                 } else {
                     g.setColor(color1);
                     g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
                     y = y + 10;
                     g.setColor(color2);
                     g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
                 }
             }
         } 
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);     <-- preferred size of panel
    }


}
```

Comment: Wow you wrote that code right out of your head, this is no copy paste^^ +1 - im impresse peeeskillet!

Comment: Updated OP based on this answer.

Comment: Just fix `painComponent()`. It's spelled wrong. Should be `paintComponent()`. Works fine after this fix. Tested and approved. :) Nice Graphic BTW

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

First, you should be calling `super.paintComponent` from your `JComponent#paintComponent` to ensure that you don't get any paint artifacts, especially because `JComponent` is transparent

Secondly, you should be adding your components first and the showing you frame...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            addComponents();
            setAttributes();
        }
    });
}
```

Should you need to add new components to your frame after it's made visible, you may need to call `revalidate` and `repaint` to ensure that the content is updated correctly...